# How to change SQL query laravel equivalent query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have written a SQL query as below

```
select id from users where fname not in (select fname from blocked_users);
```

It is working as expected. Can anyone help me to convert this to a laravel equivalent query?

Thanks.

Comment: You are not asking for help, you are asking for a complete solution without even trying it by yourself. Please share what you've done so far

Comment: I have answered your question. Check and let me know if it's working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
DB::table('users')->whereNotIn('fname', function ($query) {
    $query->select('fname')->from('blocked_users');
})->get();
```